# RegEx for string getting words without spaces, but one part could have them

Tags: java, regex, string

at first: sorry for the title, did not know any better. Also I am fairly new to regular expressions.

I am currently programming a little something which can analyse the name of an item/weapon (from a game).

I would like to match names like this one:

```
Windwalkers angry Leather Claws of Destruction
```

with the following match groups:

1. Windwalkers
2. angry
3. Leather Claws
4. Destruction

An item name has a naming scheme:

```
<> = required, [] = optional
[itemgroup] [adjective] < material name with spaces > [of [source]]
```

groups, adjectives and the source won't contain any spaces.

I came up with this:

```
(\w*) (\w*) (.+) of (.*)
```

which does not handle at all that some of the parts are optional, also it would be great if the match groups would always stay the same, so 2 would always be the adjective with the possiblity of that being blank.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can append `?` to the optional groups.

Comment: Impossible with regular expressions, unless you have only a fixed set of vocabulary.

Comment: @his true, but it's pretty safe to assume that it will have a fixed set of vocabulary (may be quite large however).

Comment: Fixed set of vocabulary is possible. I have a list of every possible word there. What would be more efficent: Regex by listing every possible word or splitting it manually and using a sorted list and using startsWith and such?

Comment: About the efficiency part. Does the valueof(Object) method of enums use efficient algorithms or do they only iterate through the enum constants (linear time)? I hope this does not get too offtopic, but if so I would create an enum for each possible word in item names.

Comment: @SeanF It is? Sounds for me like a user input should be parsed. Otherwise parsing a string would be the wrong approach (don't create a concatenated string in the first place). "Fixed" also means "very limited" if it should be useful for regex. As @Mathis now clarified it can even be done with `enum`s. Yes, do that, drop that regex part completely. The resulting string is only for output, it is _not_ a data model.

Answer (score 2):

You could split it into the parts in one line:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<!Leather|Steel|Wood(en)?|Glass|Iron|Bronze) (of )?");
```

You can add as many adjectives as you need.

This uses a negative look-behind to assert that the space being split on is not preceded by an adjective. The optional `(of )?` consumes the "of" between terms.

---

Here's a test:

```
String str = "Windwalkers angry Leather Claws of Destruction";
String[] parts = str.split("(?<!Leather|Steel|Wood(en)?|Glass|Iron|Bronze) (of )?");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[Windwalkers, angry, Leather Claws, Destruction]
```

Comment: looks promising eventhough it seems there is a lot more to learn since I don't really understand what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do what you want with regexes, since there's no way to tell whether the first word would be an itemgroup, an adjective, or part of a material name.  I think the regex approach is the wrong way to go.  Instead, consider creating a `List<String>` of the allowable itemgroups, and another `List<String>` for the adjectives and one for material names.  Then if `input` is the input name:

```
String work = input;
for (String itemgroup : itemgroupList)
    if (work.startsWith (itemgroup.concat (" ")) {
        // itemgroup is now the item group you want
        work = work.substring (itemgroup.length()).trim();
        // remove itemgroup from the front of work, and discard leftover leading
        // spaces
    }
```

This tests whether the current string starts with an itemgroup.  If it does, it removes the itemgroup from the work string, and then you can do something similar with your list of adjectives and materials.  If not, the work string isn't changed, but then you can look for adjectives and materials.  The only thing I'd use a regex for is the "of" part.  The advantage of doing this over trying to do everything with regexes is that you can easily add or remove items from any of the lists of allowable possibilities.  (Be careful when you get to the end of the input; my code above appended a space to the `itemgroup` since I figured the `itemgroup` has to be followed by a space, but that won't always be the case for the material name.)

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should give you the values you're after:

```
  ^(\w* )?(\w* )?(\w* \w*) of (\w*)$
```

The only significant assumption here is that there will be one and only one space in the item name ('Leather Claws') - if that is not the case, then I don't believe this is possible by use of regular expressions. That said, that situation would be difficult to handle on *any* automated parser, unless there's a fixed grammar that your question doesn't mention.

**Input:** `Windwalkers angry Leather Claws of Destruction`

**Output:**

1. Windwalkers
2. angry
3. Leather Claws
4. Destruction

**Input:** `Windwalkers Leather Claws of Destruction`

**Output:**

1. Windwalkers
2. <blank>
3. Leather Claws
4. Destruction

**Input:** `Leather Claws of Destruction`

**Output:**

1. <blank>
2. <blank>
3. Leather Claws
4. Destruction

These are the only test cases I could ascertain from your question, but it parses them all correctly and even keeps the same match groups.

See demonstration at http://www.rubular.com/r/7AT4kDVf8S

Answer (score 0):

```
\[([a-z A-Z]*)\]\s\[([a-z A-Z]*)\] <(.*)\>\s\[of\s\[([a-z A-Z]*)\]\]
```

here is the regex pattern. I'm a little confused about the option part that you were talking about but the use of | calls ors so maybe that can help you along with the website i provided.

() are called group which you parse the content from them.

this websites amazing for regex!

http://www.debuggex.com/

EDIT: for the optional section just make different patterns of regex and if one fails ifelse to another one that fits to another pattern.

Comment: I used the () above as you have not noticed. Also it does not work with my provided example: Windwalkers angry Leather Claws of Destruction. But thanks for the site, looks promising

Comment: [Windwalkers] [angry] < Leather Claws > [of [Destruction]]. I thought thats the string you were formating sorry for my misinterpretation. I recommend adding brackets or something for each section of the pattern sort of like how it's setup here so it's easier to parse it. with spaces and such and no identifying characters it's going to be almost impossible to parse.